# How to float left carousel left control?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to re-position the left and right carousel button controls in my lower right corner of my carousel.  However, I cannot figure out how to float the left control as doesn't float with the right?

Initial page load:

[image]

After dragging page wider:

[image]

Float is not included in the code but I've tried float:right with the left control.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev"  style="margin: 348px 0 0 770px">&lsaquo;</a>   
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next"   style="margin: 348px -20px 0 0">&rsaquo;</a>
```

I have tried putting both in a div and float right but no go.

I basically want the two carousel buttons to stay right next to each other in the lower right hand portion of the carousel.  On page load my margins re-position the next/prev buttons to the lower right hand portion and initially they appear together but when you drag the browser to the right it widens/stretches the control and the controls separate (right moves but left stays fixed).
HERE IS THE JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/LneL8/

Comment: Could you put the code on a tool like jsbin?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the left on one side and right on the right side?

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/LneL8/

Comment: @Pjack: More or less, correct!

Comment: I created an answer. I removed the margins because they were too big for the page. That might be messing you up too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do. I took out the margins for example sake. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4KR/

```
 <div id="buttons">
    <p class="floatLeft"><a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev">Left</a> </p>

    <p class="floatRight"><a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next">Right</a></p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.floatRight{
    float:right;
}
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LneL8/1/

Comment: Hi, that's not what I'm trying to do. I want the arrow buttons to stay right next to each other in the lower right hand corner like this-> http://bit.ly/139ufJI . The problem is when the page is resized (i.e. browser is dragged from left to right making the web page bigger).  The left button stays and the right moves with the page -> http://bit.ly/16ARtWh.  I want them to stay together in the lower right hand corner when the page or carousel resizes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get them on opposite sides of the page?

I looked at your jsFiddle but couldn't see the arrows.

But suppose your HTML code for arrows was as such:

```
<input type="button" class="leftArrow" value="left" />
<input type="button" class="rightArrow" value="right" />
```

To get the left arrow to "float" left and the right arrow to "float" right, add the following CSS:

```
.leftArrow { position: relative; float: left; }
.rightArrow { position: relative: float: right; }
```

**Remember: making the position "relative" is important. The floats won't work otherwise.**

Comment: Hi, that's not what I'm trying to do. I want the arrow buttons to stay right next to each other in the lower right hand corner like this-> bit.ly/139ufJI (that would be the initial position on page load). The problem is when the page is resized (i.e. browser is dragged from left to right making the web page bigger). The left button stays and the right moves with the page -> bit.ly/16ARtWh. I want them to stay together in the lower right hand corner when the page or carousel resizes.